# How to get the summation in group by statement linq query

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, group-by, linq-to-dataset

I have the following LINQ query :

```
var groupedData = from b in loans.AsEnumerable()                     
                  group b by b.Field<int>("loan_code") & b.Field<int>("emp_num")
                  into f        
                  select f.CopyToDataTable();
```

---

I want to select  `f` and in addition to that the summation of `Tot` field and copy the result in data table .how to do that?

Comment: Is it required to put data in new DataTable? Why not use some class for that?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy: yeah ,it's required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get required data

```
var groupedData = from r in loans.AsEnumerable()                     
                  group r by new { 
                      LoanCode = r.Field<int>("loan_code"),
                      EmpNum = r.Field<int>("emp_num") 
                  } into g
                  select new {
                      g.Key.LoanCode,
                      g.Key.EmpNum,
                      Tot = g.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("Tot")) // assume integer
                  };
```

Then use custom [CopyToDataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method (which works for types that don't implement DataRow) to convert them to DataTable. Or you can build DataTable manually:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("loan_code", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("emp_num", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Tot", typeof(int));

foreach(var data in groupedData)
    dt.Rows.Add(data.LoanCode, data.EmpNum, data.Tot);
```

Comment: I i want to get all fields in addition to the summation , should i add them to the `group by` part ??

Comment: @just_name you can't. Group contains many rows, which have many values. You can select aggregated values for all rows, as well as values common for all rows (i.e. grouping keys). If you will add all fields to group by part, then Tot will contain value of single row (if rows have different values in any field except Tot)